# How to sort specific table column's digits before and after decimal?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, sorting, tabs

```
<th class="column-2 sorting_desc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tablepress-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 83px;" aria-label="Section Citation: activate to sort column ascending" aria-sort="descending">Section Citation</th>
```

This is a dynamically generated table header column. Right now this columns shows values like this:

```
440.262
438.816
438.812
438.1
438.808
438.806
438.802
```

While my client wants if we click on header title (which is "Section Citation") It should first sort digits before decimal then after decimal. So that the end results should be like this

```
438.1
438.802
438.806
438.808
438.812
438.816
440.262
```

I hope this makes sense?

My friend helped me do it how client needed. But he added two buttons at the top of the table (outside of table) but the problem is client doesn't want those buttons he wants the column header to have this function work.

Can anyone please help me?

Table is available here: http://www.justiceinaging.org/medicaid-managed-care-tool/

BTW I am using WordPress and I am using TablePress plugin to display tables.